# Is there a macro for ifstream and ofstream or a way to shorten ifstream/ofstream?

Tags: c++, macros

For example if my file name is : sum00.in, sum.00.out, is there a possibility excepting the one of writing each time the same piece of code:

```
ifstream in("sum00.in");
ofstream out("sum00.out");
```

I first thought of macro:

```
#define read(x) ifstream in("x.in"); ofstream out("x.out"); ///But it doesn`t work for a word.
```

Every advice that would help me writing the same piece of could would be helpful!

Comment: If that's a pattern that you use that many times, why not excapsulate it in a `class`?

Comment: Why are you calling your variables `cin` and `cout`?  There already is a `std::cin` and `std::cout`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo can you show me an example of code of a class ifstream ofstream?

Comment: @BenjaminStarck Ok, I added an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend not using a macro. I'd encapsulate it in a class.

Example:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class MyIO {
public:
    explicit MyIO(const std::string& basename) :
        in(basename + ".in"),
        out(basename + ".out")
    {}
    std::ifstream& is() { return in; }
    std::ofstream& os() { return out; }

private:
    std::ifstream in;
    std::ofstream out;
};

int main() {
    MyIO f("sum001");      // open both sum001.in and sum001.out
    int i;
    int sum = 0;
    while(f.is() >> i) {   // read from the ifstream
        sum += i;
    }
    f.os() << sum << '\n'; // write to the ofstream
}
```